# siunitx does not detect number style

Tags: fontspec, siunitx

Siunitx does not recognise the oldstyle numbers, despite the `detect-all` setting,
can you help me?

MNWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\newfontfamily\oldstyle[Numbers={Monospaced,OldStyle}]{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
  \oldstyle\num{123}123
\end{document}
```

This results in:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just convince **siunitx** to use your newly created font family by:

```
\sisetup{text-rm=\oldstyle}
```

full example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\newfontfamily\oldstyle[Numbers={Monospaced,OldStyle}]{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}

\AtBeginDocument{
\sisetup{text-rm=\oldstyle}
}

\begin{document}
  \oldstyle\num{123}123
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You are forced to do that, as said in the manual:

> The siunitx package controls the font used to print output
>   independently of the surrounding material. The standard method is to
>   ignore the surroundings entirely, and to use the current body fonts.

To work against that, there are just a few possibilities:

**`detect-all`** combines the following four single commands

- `detect-weight`
- `detect-family`
- `detect-shape`
- `detect-mode`

So it does not detect **all** - the name is therefore a little misleading.

The number style is a rather particular font setting which is not included in `detect-all`.

---

As **siunitx** is intended to be used for scientific notations of numbers and units it is rather comprehensible that the number style can't be changed that easily as it wouldn't look *"scientific"* anymore. I'm using old-style numbers in my thesis as well for chapter numbers etc. and I was actually expecting `siunitx` to adapt this setting at first, but gladly welcomed that it doesn't.

Comment: Explicitly setting it is not really the point of _detect_, is it?

Comment: @MaxNoe have a look at my edit.