# siunitx 'detect-all' does not honor fontspec's math font in Beamer

Tags: beamer, luatex, fontspec, siunitx, unicode-math

## Problem statement

The `\sisetup{detect-all}` option of the `siunitx` package does not work for me as expected in a Beamer presentation, which I would like to typeset as follows:

- Text in Latin Modern Sans (sans serif)
- Math in TeX Gyre Pagella Math (serif)

For reasons beyond this MWE, my setup requires `lualatex` and `\usepackage{siunitx}`. I would like the `siunitx` package to detect whether it is being used in text or math mode and adjust the font accordingly, which I understand is typically done using `\sisetup{detect-all}`.

## MWE to illustrate the problem

The following MWE (compiled with `lualatex`) shows how **Beamer incorrectly uses the sans font for `siunitx` macros in math mode**.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}% Turn fonts over to 'fontspec'
%\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}% Does /not/ solve the problem

\usepackage{fontspec}%
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}%
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}%

\usepackage{unicode-math}%
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}%

\usepackage{siunitx}%

\sisetup{%
  detect-all,%
}%


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Regular numbers in text mode: sans font, as expected: 2469
    \item SI numbers in text mode: sans font, as expected: \num{2469}
    \item Numbers in math mode: math font, as expected: $2469$
    \item SI numbers in math mode: sans font (not expected): $\num{2469}$  % <== !!!
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## MWE to demonstrate that this problem is specific to Beamer

It appears that this problem is specific to `\documentclass{beamer}`, since the following MWE for `\documentclass{article}` (again compiled with `lualatex`) **works entirely as expected**.

```
\documentclass{article}%

\usepackage{fontspec}%
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}%
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}%

\usepackage{unicode-math}%
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}%

\usepackage{siunitx}%

\sisetup{%
  detect-all,%
}%

\begin{document}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item Regular numbers in text mode: main font, as expected: 2469
    \item SI numbers in text mode: main font, as expected: \num{2469}
    \item Numbers in math mode: math font, as expected: $2469$
    \item SI numbers in math mode: math font, as expected: $\num{2469}$
  \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Non-satisfactory workaround

In the following MWE, which was inspired by [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241086/38212) and compiled with `lualatex`, `siunitx` commands use the correct math font. I've added an additional `equation*` environment to distinguish between inline and display math (as the required `\sisetup` options that I have added also do).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}% Turn fonts over to 'fontspec'
%\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}% Did /not/ solve the problem

\usepackage{fontspec}%
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}%
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}%

\usepackage{unicode-math}%
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}%
\newfontfamily\mymathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}% <== NEWLY ADDED

\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{%
  math-rm=\mymathfont,%       <== NEWLY ADDED
  detect-all,%
  detect-display-math=true,%  <== NEWLY ADDED
  detect-inline-family=math,% <== NEWLY ADDED
  detect-inline-weight=math,% <== NEWLY ADDED
}%


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Regular numbers in text mode: sans font, as expected: 2469
    \item SI numbers in text mode: sans font, as expected: \num{2469}
          \item Numbers in math mode: math font, as expected: $2469$
    \item SI numbers in inline math: math font (now as expected): $\num{2469}$% <== NOW WORKS
    \item SI numbers in display math: math font (as expected)
      \begin{equation*}
        \num{2469}
      \end{equation*}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Why I do not consider this workaround a satisfactory solution

- In an example more complex than the above MWEs, the workaround breaks compilation (I'm still analyzing why that might be the case)
- I still do not know why the problem only appears in Beamer, but not article, which makes me think that a more satisfactory solution might actually have to be grounded in Beamer, not `siunitx`.
- I now need to effectively define my math font twice, which makes the code harder to maintain.

Comment: It seems that a workaround is to `\newfontfamily\mymathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}` after `\setmathfont` and then add  `math-rm=\mymathfont,` as well as `detect-inline-family=math` and `detect-inline-weight=math` to the `\sisetup` block (inspired by http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241086/38212). However, I don't quite understand whether this is actually the best solution, and more importantly *why* it's necessary to explicitly tell siunitx about the math-rm font.

Comment: Also, why is this required for beamer, but not for article?

Comment: Maybe because the `beamer` default fonts is sans serif?

Comment: Yes, I thought so too, but notice that `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}` did *not* solve the problem (I included this as a commented line in the original MWE after having tried it without success myself). I also just confirmed that the line does not solve the problem in combination with the newly added `detect-*` options in `\sisetup`; any working solution I have still relies on the `\newfontfamily` and `math-rm` commands shown in the workaround above.

Comment: Interesting, a `\usefonttheme{serif}` (without the `[onlymath]` option) actually results in the correct math font (TeX Gyre Pagella) also for SI numbers in math mode, even *without* the `\newfontfamily` macro and `math-rm` sisetup option. (But of course now *all* of my presentation is in serif fonts).

Comment: Beamer does `\def\familydefault{\sfdefault}`. If you add that, you can reproduce in `article`. It also uses `\mathfamilydefault`. That can be set to `\rmdefault` or `\sfdefault`. Neither of which is what you want here....

Comment: I didn't trace through the details but this is running up against different frameworks for font selection, for both text and maths. Beamer is assuming one framework. You are trying to customise using another. What does your setting of the maths font correspond to in the traditional framework? Nothing at all....

Comment: Use `serif` for the font theme across the board and set the main font to Latin Modern Sans. Do you need Schola for anything? Probably not. If you do, maybe define a special font family for that.

Comment: I can confirm that adding `\def\familydefault{\sfdefault}` in the preample of the second MWE (right after `\documentclass{article}`) breaks that MWE in the same way as the first MWE in Beamer. Yes, I think you're right about the different font frameworks, but I'm still hoping for a solution of some sort (that also compiles in my actual project, not just this MWE).

Comment: Or you can say e.g. `\def\mathfamilydefault{\mymathfont}` if you want to keep Schola as serif for some reason. (But this strikes me as almost certainly overdoing font varieties in a single document, especially a presentation. Two serifs?)

Comment: Nice idea: using `\setfonttheme{serif}` and then `\setmainfont{Latin Modern Sans}` actually seems to work! That being said, I actually *do* use Schola, because I use the same .tex source for both, and article and a Beamer presentation, using Beamer's article mode. So I was hoping to define the article text font via `\setmainfont`, the Beamer text font via `\setsansfont`, and the math font that they both share via `\setmathfont`. Could work around that via `\only<presentation>{\setmainfont{Latin Modern Sans}}` & `\only<article>{\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}}`, but perhaps there is a better way?

Comment: I don't think so. Unless you want to start rewriting Beamer code. As far as Beamer is concerned, the default family for maths is either `\rmdefault` or `\sfdefault`. Either you make it think it needs to do nothing or you change what it thinks it needs to do. I'd use `\mode<article>...` etc. for the font setup and thank my lucky stars I didn't have to trace through the maze which is Beamer's code. You may naturally feel differently. (At least until you look at the maze.)

Comment: Sounds reasonable. So far still cannot get my (way larger) project to compile using this approach, though. Fails with a `Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \c__siunitx_mathsf_int`

Comment: It does depend what you mean by 'better'. 'Better' would be fixing Beamer, but also fixing **fontspec** using a time machine. (That is, I think it is probably too late to change it now, but it would have been better, IMNSHO, to not break the NFSS quite so completely e.g. serif -> 'main' is not helpful, in my opinion.)

Comment: Hard to say without an example. I can't see why anything should break no matter which way you set the fonts. You might get the wrong result, but that's a bit different.

Comment: I think that `\c__siunitx_mathsf_int` should be defined somewhere, but I can't find it. Maybe it is defined implicitly. I recommend asking a follow-up question with that error in the subject line to make sure that it gets seen by the package author. Probably this question will, too, especially as it is Beamer. But best be sure in case he's short of time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for roughly the reasons explained in the comments:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Sans}%TeX Gyre Schola}
% \setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{%
  detect-all,%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Regular numbers in text mode: sans font, as expected: 24693
    \item SI numbers in text mode: sans font, as expected: \num{24693}
    \item Numbers in math mode: math font, as expected: $24693$
    \item SI numbers in math mode: sans font (not expected): $\num{24693}$  % <== !!!
  \end{itemize}
  \[ \sin \theta^2 + \cos \theta^2 = 1 \num{2469} \]
  $x^3 + f(y) = \sqrt[5]{z}$

  1234567890

  $1234567890$

  $\num{1234567890}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Beamer with unicode maths]

Comment: Mmh, I don't quite understand why the `detect-display-math` and `detect-inline-*` options are no longer required in `\sisetup`?

Comment: Because setting `serif` stops, I think, the font switching associated with the default maths and text families when you switch in and out. And somehow, **siunitx** is sensitive to that even though **unicode-math** overrides it. I think. Like I said, I didn't trace this through Beamer's code. I had a `grep` and then guessed what might work, based on half an idea of what might be going wrong. Too sleepy now to thing carefully about it. Joseph will know, though ;). (Or you can ask for your money back.)